# Unable to connect IBAction to UITextField in XIB (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, ibaction

On one of my ViewControllers, I declared:

```
@IBOutlet var priceTextField : UITextField!
```

Then I tried to add the following based on the same UITextField:

```
 @IBAction func priceTextFieldChanged(sender: UITextField) { updateOutput() }
```

When I looked at the XIB's File Owner and at the Received Actions, I was not able to connect the UITextField to this function for some reason. I even tried to drag that UITextField to the ViewController, but was not able to see the "Action" option. I checked the class. It's linked to the ViewController. Not sure what to do here.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

A `UITextField` does not provide an action (`sendAction:`), that is why you can't hook-it-up.

What you need is to create a delegate, for `textFieldDidBeginEditing` or another delegate method of `UITextField` and set the `UITextField` delegate to your class instance.

Comment: let me try provide an example below to make sure I understand your point.

Answer (score 1):

@Zaph, something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var priceTextField : UITextField!

func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
if let value = sender.textIntegerValue() {
            pricetepper.ifInRangeSetValue(value)
        }
        updateOutput()
 }
}
```

Not sure if I pick the right method. Thanks.

Comment: You also have to set the `UITextField`'s delegate to the class: `priceTextField.delegate = self`